# CAN receiver buffer is not getting filled,receiver interrupt is not called why?

Tags: buffer, call, interrupt, can-bus, receiver

I am using R5F10BAC(uc) and PCAN to send an array at regular fixed time by calling transmission function, after transmission done, I want to receive that by calling receive function(there is no other CAN nodes used). Receiver buffers (RFDF00L, RFDF00H, RFDF10L, RFDF10H, RFDF20L, RFDF20H, RFDF30L, RFDF30H) are always 0x00.

There is a interrupt function that is called once data arrives, but it is never called, I checked by placing a (count) variable in it. Variable is not changing. I am using FIFO Buffer 0 to receive. I am getting transmitted message in PCAN as Rx continuously. Port1 0th bit is set for transmit, Port1 1st bit is set for receiving (saw changes in SFR). Should I use INTP0(external Interrupt)? Does any one knew, please clarify.

Comment: What makes you think it's a software problem? Have you measured the Rx pin from the transceiver and verified that data is coming in there?

Comment: Yes Sir, Port1 is updating after transmission  from 0x72 to 0x73 i.e port 10 for transmission, port 11 for reception